# Azure mobile apps service - local debugging on MAC

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-mac

Environment: VS 2017 MAC Professional

I created an **Azure Mobile App Quick Start** application service.  I appear to run and start the application without issues as I receive the **This mobile app is up and running** message.

I am receiving **Resource not found** errors when navigating to the controller action (GET Request).

URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/TodoItem/GetTodoItem

```
Application Exception
System.Web.HttpException
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Details: Requested URL: /TodoItem/GetTodoItem
Exception stack trace:
at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00094] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/StaticFileHandler.cs:77 
at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0007f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/DefaultHttpHandler.cs:101 
at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>d__225.MoveNext () [0x008d4] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1335 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:927 
Version Information: 5.4.0.212 (2017-06/fbc487ff424 Fri Oct 6 06:41:39 EDT 2017); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.42000
```

All I want to is to debug the code locally. Why is the resource not found?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all your ToDoItems the GET request URL would look like this:
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/tables/TodoItem

To get a specific ToDoItem record, add the record id to the URL:
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/tables/TodoItem/44941398-2C4F-4733-864F-2B629DB0B66A